# Can't find the /var/www/test/ directory (Mac OSX)

Tags: python-3.x, apache, directory

I'm learning python and now I arrived at 'The web' where I'm told about Apache. They ask me to create a simple file (see below) and save it as /var/www/test/home.wsgi but I can't find a directory like this and don't understand what I have to do here.

I looked for the directory but can't find it, then I started searching on google but can't find the solution.

```
import bottle

application = bottle.default_app()
@bottle.route('/')
def home():
    return "apache and wsgi, sitting in a tree"
```

Anyone got any idea of what to do here?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @jorijnsmit no, on a mac

Comment: `/var/www/` is sometimes the default directory for Apache. That directory may just help you for Apache to "find" it.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/www/` is typically the root folder used by Apache for its hosted files. If it doesn't exist on your system, chances are you do not have Apache installed or have it configured to use a different folder.

On my Macbook I was able to track down this folder by checking the `DocumentRoot` setting in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Not sure what you are trying to do in the grand scheme of things but chances are you will have to configure Apache properly before being able to visit files in your root folder through http://localhost/.